# Merge two or more drawingImage's in one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Good day!
Is it possible to create new drawing image, that contains two or more another drawing images defined in another xaml-files?

For example: i have Icon1.xaml and Icon2.xaml files, that contains drawing images definitions. I want to create new drawing image, that contains those images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrawingImage uses a drawing of some sort as it's source. If you have a reference to whichever of those options that is out of:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx

These sound like they're your application iconography so you have precise control of them.
Assuming this is the case then you can combine them as a drawing group. As in group of drawings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-composite-drawing

In the above link you have geometrydrawings and whatnot directly in the XAML.
They could instead be keyed resources which are merged from other resource dictionaries.

```
<DrawingGroup>
  <GeometryDrawing Geometry={StaticResource YourGeometryKey/>
```

If you define your various shapes as Geometry then this gives you the most flexibility. This is how I'd usually do iconography like save floppies etc.

In order to reference a resource from one resourcedictionary in another, merge them all in app.xaml. The order matters. So you need the dependencies merged first then you should be able to use them in another resource dictionary.